# Destructuring argument with object and key from destructured object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is it possible to obtain a destructured variable from the object that gets passed in by using another destructured argument as the key?

```
var test = { 
    a: { 
        b: 'c' 
    },
    access: 'b' 
};

myFunc(test);

function myFunc( { a : { access /*???*/ } } ) {
    console.log(/*???*/);  // should output 'c'
}
```

working way -

```
function myFunc( { a, access }) {
    console.log(a[access]);  // should output 'c'
}
```

Comment: You probably meant to declare: `function myFunc (c) {...` and call the function with: `myFunc(test.a.b);`

Comment: By the way it's called destruct**ur**ing not destructing.

Comment: The destructuring should be `{ a: { b } }`, then if you use `b` it would contain `'c'`

Comment: @zerkms thanks, but i was mistaken about what i was trying to get and use, i updated the question

Comment: @alfasin i'm trying to get the value inside an object passed in, assume i don't control how the object is passed in

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks, typo :)

Comment: No, you cannot do it simply with a single destructuring.

Comment: @zerkms actually... passing `test` in and declaring the function as: `function myFunc( { a : { b: c } } ) { console.log(c); }` works. But doing something like this is bad, bad, bad...

Comment: @alfasin i'm not sure that would be what i want or why it would be bad :), i added the 'working way' solution in the question to be more explicit about what i want to obtain

Comment: @alfasin it works but it's not what OP asked for. The key `b` is stored in the property `access`, it's an additional indirection.

Comment: @zerkms well now that he modified his question...

Comment: @alfasin check the history, it was there before my upvoted comment. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47763647/3 --- it was added 30 minutes ago.

Comment: I see, probably my view wasn't refreshed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using computed property names:

```
function myFunc( { access, a : { [access]: val } } ) {
    console.log(val); // does output 'c' when called with test
}
```

You will need to ensure that `access` is initialised first though, before accessing the property of `a`.

I would however recommend to avoid this, it will confuse the heck out of any reader. Don't try to be clever. Your working way is also the most readable way.

Comment: people need to learn tricks to think smarter about what they can accomplish with a language, i don't mind confusing anyone

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer I don't mind to learn either, but still I would avoid this in production code and use the simpler option.

Comment: @Bergi everything gets scrambled, minified and obfuscated in production ;-), it's even more of a mess

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer I meant "production-level" code as opposed to code for experiments, toy examples and hobby projects. I wouldn't use this style of code where maintainability is key.

Comment: seems like an arbitrary line in the sand